# Angular 2 shared module circular dependency

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a share module that looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    OneModule,
    TwoModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

The OneModule imports the SharedModule because he needs access to the other shared modules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [SomeComponent]
})
export class OneModule {

}
```

When I console log the SharedModule I get undefined because I have circular dependency. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SharedModule` imports `OneModule` which imports `SharedModule` which imports `OneModule` and so on.

To avoid this, you should try to make `SharedModule` have a `SharedService` that you can include in all your components, try to regroup the 'logical thinking' of your code in services.